# How to check a value in a series is unique

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, unique

I am trying to test out if a value in a `series` is a unique value. I know `series.unique` can give an array of unique values in the `series`, but not sure how it fit in my case. Or iterate through the `series`, but it's not very efficient, so I am wondering is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with parameter `keep=False` and then invert boolean `Series` by `~`:

```
print df
  col
0   a
1   b
2   a
3   b
4   c

print df.col.duplicated(keep=False)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: col, dtype: bool

print ~df.col.duplicated(keep=False)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
Name: col, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

You could combine boolean indexing and built-in `len()` to get the exact amount of instances of a given value.

Assuming your `DataFrame` looks like this:

```
In [155]: test_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([1,2,3,3,4]), columns=['A'])

In [156]: test_1
Out[156]: 
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  3
4  4
```

You can get the amount of instances of value `3` or `1` like this:

```
In [158]: len(test_1[test_1.A == 3])
Out[158]: 2 ## two instances make for non-unique value

In [159]: len(test_1[test_1.A == 1])
Out[159]: 1 ## Unique value!!
```

This way you can define the exact value you want to test and get the amount of instances of this value.